# Unable to use Swift debugger in one particular class file

Tags: swift, lldb

I'm able to use the debugger to see values in memory everywhere in my app except one class. Every time I try, no matter what value I try to `po`, I get the same error message:

```
(lldb) po searchInstitution.name
error: <EXPR>:2:1: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Device'
searchInstitution.name
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<EXPR>:15:7: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Device'
  if (1==1) {                                          
      ^
```

`Device` is a struct in the file with this definition:

```
private struct Device: Hashable {
    let type: String
    let mask: String

    var hashValue: Int {
        return type.hashValue ^ mask.hashValue
    }
}

private func ==(lhs: Device, rhs: Device) -> Bool {
    return lhs.type == rhs.type && lhs.mask == rhs.mask
}
```

But it has nothing to do with the string property of the SearchInstitution class instance that I'm trying to inspect.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Any ideas on what I may need to change to fix it? It makes debugging that view controller extremely frustrating.

Comment: I would file a bug report on that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug.  The conflict with the "if (1 == 1)" in the code the expression parser uses to wrap your expression is fixed in github lldb (by switching to "do" - which wasn't available when this code was first written...), and should make it into the next official tools release.

If you want to work around it in the meantime, just make your == operator public rather than private.  The expression evaluator was trying to force priority for local private definitions over potentially conflicting global ones, and didn't do it correctly so that ONLY the private local one was seen.

Note, that more general bug is not fixed yet, so if you actually use a private operator in a context where it is visible, ONLY that operator definition will be used.